# C++, linux, how to pass a not static method from a singleton to pthread_create?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, g++, pthreads

I have a problem with threading a not static method from a singleton class,look at the code :

```
//g++ main.cc -lpthread
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>                 
#include<pthread.h>

class SLAYER{
  private:
    SLAYER(){};
    ~SLAYER(){};
    static SLAYER *singleton;
    pthread_t t1, t2;

  public: 
    static void *born(){
      singleton = new SLAYER;
    };
    static void *death(){
      delete singleton;
      singleton = NULL;
    };
    static void *start(){
      pthread_create(&singleton->t1,NULL,singleton->KerryRayKing, NULL);
      pthread_create(&singleton->t2,NULL,singleton->JeffHanneman, NULL);
    };
    void *JeffHanneman(void *arg){
      sleep(1);
      std::cout << "(1964-2013) R.I.P.\n";
      (void) arg;
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    };
    static void *KerryRayKing(void *arg){
      sleep(1);
      std::cout << "(1964-still with us) bald\n";
      (void) arg;
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    };
};

SLAYER *SLAYER::singleton=NULL;

int main(){
  SLAYER::born();
  SLAYER::start();
  std::cout << "thread started\n";
  sleep(5);
  SLAYER::death();
  return 0;
}
```

as you can see `KerryRayKing()` is static unlike `JeffHanneman()`. I failed to pass `JeffHanneman()` to `pthread_create()`, at compilation time I got :

```
cannot convert ‘SLAYER::JeffHanneman’ from type ‘void* (SLAYER::)(void*)’ to type ‘void* (*)(void*)’
```

I tried several cast, but failed... isn't possible to use in this cas a non static method ?

## edit :

I forgot to say, I don't want to allow access to `JeffHanneman()` from outside

Comment: Use a class static or global helper method. And BTW, try to encapsulate the ownership of the thread handle inside your singleton class.

Comment: You may want to use `std::thread` (if you have C++11 enabled) or `boost::thread` instead of raw pthreads.

Comment: Take note that pthread_create takes a C function pointer. Which is not compatible with a C++ member function.

Comment: I wonder if boost and std::thread aren't just wrappers of pthread

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't do that.

There are several workarounds, the simplest is to have `static` wrapper function, e.g.

```
static void *JHWrapper(void *self)
{
   SLAYER *that = static_cast<SLAYER*>(self);
   return that->JeffHanneman(); 
}

void *JeffHanneman(){   // Note "arg" removed.
  sleep(1);
  std::cout << "(1964-2013) R.I.P.\n";
  pthread_exit(NULL);
};
```

Now, the pthread create becomes:

```
 pthread_create(&singleton->t1,NULL, SLAYER::JHWrapper, static_cast<void *>(singleton));
```

[I refrained from the pun of "JHRapper", as I think that would be rather demeaning...]

Comment: reinterpret_cast is unnecessary here.  static_cast will do and is therefor to be preferred.

Comment: even `static_cast` is unnecessary as `SLAYER*` is implicitly convertible to `void*`.

Comment: In both directions? In C++? I thought implicit conversions was only C?

Comment: well guys, @Mats Petersson : I feel stupid, because in my case I just needed to put `JeffHanneman()` as static in private... anyway your code interest me, I never see a static cast before. I have to admit I don't understand your code, especially the this in a static method, I need to do some search... oh and I don't know who is JHRapper I guess it's a rapper...  @CrazyEddie : are you the guy of "Crazy Eddie's GUI"  ?

Comment: @bob'swoodenleg: JHRapper is a joke - JeffHanneman is of course not a Rapper, but the function is called JHWrapper (JeffHanneman Wrapper), which is pronounced the same as JHRapper - it's a form of play on words. You'll find programmers do that from time to time. The `*this` in the JHWrapper function is just a variable name, it could be called `x` or `that` or some other name. `static_cast` is used to convert from one type to another (within some limits, the compiler will object if you try to do it "wrong").

Comment: You are right, it is a reserved word, I should have called it something else...Now fixed...